# inserting between condition in sum condition

Tags: mysql, sql

```
HAVING SUM (DECODE (account_number, '1', 1, 0)) > :p_num_to
```

I want to integrate between condition into sum condition, user will enter two variables `:p_num_from`  and `p:_num_to`.

Comment: HAVING between (:p_num_from >= SUM (DECODE (vrsta_promjene, '1', 1, 0))AND  SUM (DECODE (account_number, '1', 1, 0))> :p_num_to) ,
something like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add another condition with `AND`

```
HAVING (SUM (DECODE (account_number, '1', 1, 0)) <p_num_to)
AND (SUM (DECODE (account_number, '1', 1, 0))>p_num_from)
```